# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore [FromForm]IFormCollection

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following action in my .NET Core 2 controller. It is an API that should store all data posted as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
[HttpPost("data/add/{formid}"]
public void Add(int formid, [FromForm]IFormCollection formData) {
    //do something
}
```

So the Swagger UI allows to try the action using UI:
[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gss7k.png)

But the Swagger UI produces POST with body: **formData=field1%3Dvalue1%26field2%3Dvalue2**

I expect it to be: **field1=value1&field2=value2**

So the question is, is it a limitation of OpenAPI, or a bug of the SwaggerUI? Or maybe there is a way to get what I expect?

Answer (score 2):

`IFormCollection` is a dynamic dictionary, so Swagger doesn't know how to handle it, since it effectively has no rules. That in an of itself should be enough to signal to you that this isn't something you should be using in a REST-based API. The whole point is to make the API self-documenting, which means it should accept the actual stuff it needs as strongly-typed params, not a generic data dump.

In other words, instead, do something like:

```
public void Add(int formid, [FromForm]DataClass data)
```

Where `DataClass` is an actual class with properties that match the names of the fields you're posting. Using a strongly-typed param does not preclude posting as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. There's really no good reason to ever use `IFormCollection`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris. Well, sure I can create a class that will have a collection of Key/Value, and then post it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded (REST really does not mean that you should use application/json). But simply IFormCollection is something from the box, that could work from the box